# Apply HTML formatting to contenteditable div while typing

Tags: jquery, dom, contenteditable, caret

I'm trying to dynamically update the text a user inputs into a contenteditable div by applying HTML formatting to certain parts of the text. Using jQuery and a jQuery caret plugin (https://github.com/accursoft/caret) this is what I have so far:

```
   $("#edit").on("input",function(e){
      var text=$(this).text();
      var pos = $("#edit").caret();
      var replacement=text.replace(/([0-9]+)/g,'<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
      $("#edit").html(replacement);
      $("#edit").caret(pos); 
    });
```

I want the user to be able to keep typing while HTML formatting is dynamically applied, hence the need to manipulate the position of the caret. Without manipulating the position of the caret, it returns to the beginning of the text each time the text is updated.

Saving the position of the caret on input and then setting the caret to that position after updating the text content works when HTML formatting is not being applied, but as soon as the formatting is applied, the following error is reported:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection':
>   The offset 8 is larger than the node's length

It seems like for some reason the HTML tagged version of the text is not being counted as part of the string length. Is there any way I can work around this?